# bcoin example conf file?

Tags: documentation

Hey I've been looking around for an example conf file and I can't find one. I'm not sure how to put some parameters in. Do I do

`prune=True`

Or

`prune`

as in the documentation it says 'default: false'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it at the bottom of some documentation

https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/blob/master/etc/sample.conf

`prune: True`